# Windows Authentication & Folder Read Access

Tags: asp.net, iis, file-permissions, windows-authentication

I have a folder in which I store all of my applications. Right now 'Everyone' has read access to that folder, and certain sub-folders grand full access to everyone in order for them to be able to store files through my web-applications.

I am using Windows Authentication in order to retrieve the username which the user is currently logged in with.

I would like to disable the option for users (who are part of the 'Everyone' group obviously) to browse through the content of my applications folder and view my application files (and remove certain files). I was trying to use an Anonymous Authentication and it worked fine, but I was unable to retrieve the username the user is logged in with.

Any suggestions? I am lost.

Comment: what about storing username in session variable?

Comment: @ImadoddinIbnAlauddin where would I get the username from in the first place?

Comment: @ImadoddinIbnAlauddin I do not use any login pages in my applications. The company I am working for has a closed network, each user identifies by simply accessing the application and the permissions are given accordingly based on the username.

Comment: Why don't you just change the permissions on the folder?

Comment: @HarryJohnston If the logged-in user has no permission to read from the folder, while using Windows Authentication, he won't be able to access the website.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get widows identity then extract its name property.

```
    WindowsIdentity identity = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity;
    string username =  identity.Name;
```

Comment: Wouldn't give me what I want if the application is set to Anonymous Authentication - instead it prints "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" as my username. If it's set to Windows Authentication I wouldn't be able to access the website if I dont set the application's folder 'Read' permission to a group my user belongs to. Instead, it promts me a login screen in which I'm supposed to type in my username and password in order to identify.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your requirement. Why you would change Windows Auth to Anonymous Auth?

Comment: It's the only way I managed to think of to restrict the users from accessing the physical path of my 'applications' folder within my server. I granted the application pool full access to the folder, and now when a user accesses one of my applications through the website url it impersonates the app's pool permissions and grants him access to the application folder, however, the user wont be able to access the folder through the file path (\\webserver\applications\..). Despite that, I can't get the logged-in username that way.

Comment: Change the permissions on the share, or remove it.